# how to change direction of window location after a POST request with GET function

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

i'm working on a form connection secure with jwt, so i have to do a get request with the token given after a success of the post request.

I've tried to change location with window.location.href but by doing this (it'es like a get request) and without my token so i'll get 403 because i don't have token signed by server.

Server Side:

```
   app.post('/',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
        //data base verification
                const myToken=jwt.sign({iss:"locahost:8080",user:req.body.email,role:"moderator",admin:false},app.get('secret'));
                res.status(200).json(myToken);


});
```

```
app.get('/home',function (req,res){
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+'/views/admin.html');
});
```

Client side:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
            if(JSON.parse(xhr.response)=="access-denied"){
                createAlert("alert alert-danger","Email ou mot de passe incorrect");
            }else{
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                homeRequest();
            }       
        }
    }               
    var payLoad = "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password; 
    xhr.send(payLoad);   
}
```

```
function homeRequest(){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",'/home',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token'));
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status ==200){
            console.log('xhr response ',xhr.response);
        }
    }  
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

my actual results is have the entier page in my xhr response but i want when my POST request done i'll do a GET request to an other route in my case i want to GET /home with token in header so the server accept and send me this page but the problem i still in the routes / and i can't load this routes .

Sorry if is not enough clear :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem with saving your token unless your other code in server side is doing wrong. You can always use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`
Although your question is not so clear. You can debug by `loggin` results, here are a few suggestions:
First, try to `console.log` after receiving an answer to the post request, to see what are you receiving
Also, try to `console.log` in server's get function, check if there is such file existing

Comment: If it will not be solved, then you can add your log to your question, to get it more clear

Comment: thank you for your answer, if i dot console.log i'll get the page i'm wondering but in the window i still in the route '/'  not '/home' i want some like redirection if you see what i mean ?

Comment: This is my console.log  
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Acceuil</title>  
    </head>    
    <body class="text-center">    
            <table class="table table-bordered" >
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="user_table_body">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        .... other thing here
    </body>
```</html>

Comment: Is your client and server in the same URL?

Comment: If not use the absolute path in client side

Comment: If you just wanted to render another page then you don't need to implement get request there are other ways for routing. You should configure your node.js server completely for that

Comment: That is why it is giving such an error (403 - forbidden)

Comment: thank again , yes my node.js routes are configurated with get and post routes but the problem is redirection, what i exactly want if user connection success i want to redirect to an other page with token in headers -->like get connection in facebook before your enter your information www.facebook.com after that if it's good you get redirected to www.facebook.com/something